# R: Find and delete line with specific date

Tags: r, date, posixct

I`m pretty new to R.
Here is my problem:
I have a huge .txt file with 100k lines, 
the task is to delete all the lines which contains date later than, for  example, this month.

Date is in format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00`

Example of a line, but it may contain non constant number of words: `INFO: 2018-11-21T09:53:55.467550+00:00 (none) setaupasqa[12]: 0012f73ad1a26`

I already have tried such approach (datetime functions) to find date, but seems it`s not working

```
Date <- read.delim("my_data.txt")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format= "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00", tz="UTC")
as.POSIXlt(Date)$year + 1900
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` for this.
Sample example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- fread("sample.txt", header = F)
df$V2 <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$V2)

#Filter all rows with month >= 11
df %>%
  filter(month(V2) >= 11)
V1                  V2     V3              V4            V5
1 INFO: 2018-11-22 09:53:55 (none) setaupasqa[12]: 0012f73ad1a26
```

## Sample Data

```
$ cat sample.txt
INFO: 2018-10-21T09:53:55.467550+00:00 (none) setaupasqa[12]: 0012f73ad1a26
INFO: 2018-11-22T09:53:55.467550+00:00 (none) setaupasqa[12]: 0012f73ad1a26
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I have problem with parsing file, the reason is I have lines of different size from 4 to 20 words:

```> df <- fread("full-17-04(33%).log", header = F)
Warning message:
In fread("full-17-04(33%).log", header = F) :
  Stopped early on line 10. Expected 2 fields but found 15. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. ...

> df$V2 <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$V2)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
```
Any suggestions how can I fix it?

Comment: Are all rows in the data following the same format?

Comment: No, in different, same of them even don contains "date" e.g.:
```
WARN:  Skip timeout check
Summary: 
```